# Static library does not work on different devices

Tags: iphone, static-libraries, ios9, xcode7

I made library named as 'libDigitalSignature.a' in Xcode 7/iOS 9 and compile it on iPhone 4s.  I implemented this library file in a different app and it is working properly on iPhone 4s. But when I run the same app on iPhone 6+, it gives me the following error:

[image]

I got the same error in vice versa. Do I need to make this library on possible devises then merge all the '.a' file using following command:

lipo -create "libLogger_simulator.a" "libLogger_device.a" -output "libLogger.a"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to set Build Active Architecture Only to NO when you make your static library. Also, I would not recommend using a static library with Xcode 7. There are a lot of advantages to using a framework instead.

Comment: Thanks for your recommendation.

Answer (score 0):

You have to recompile the static library with `arm64` architecture.

Select your target and then you build settings

[image]

---

The **iPhone 5s/6/6+/6s/6s+** all are 64 bit, so to run on these devices you need to recompile your libarary with latest settings as mentioned above

Comment: how can I do this? And in that case I have two library files?

Comment: you just need to change the architecture and rest you can do the same, the simulator lib is `x86` and `x86_64` architecture